# Oval not being completely filled

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm currently doing some messing around with python's Tkinter module and classes. I'm experiencing a problem when using create_oval on a canvas where using the fill=[color] is only filling in a small dot in the circle. My code is as follows.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class MainApplication(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.parent = parent
        self.canvas(parent)
        self.draw_oval()


def canvas(self, parent):
    self.canvas = tk.Canvas(parent, width=960, height=600)
    self.canvas.pack()   

def draw_oval(self):
    self.canvas.create_oval(300, 300, 300, 300, width=200, fill='green')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()
    MainApplication(root).pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Im not sure what the problem is. Any and all criticism welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an oval that is zero pixels wide and zero pixels tall (the upper left corner is 300,300, the lower right is 300,300). The fact that you see anything at all is that you are forcing it to use a really thick line to draw around the edge.

If you want a 200 pixel wide/long oval, you control that with the coordinates, not the width:

```
def draw_oval(self):
    self.canvas.create_oval(300, 300, 500, 500, width=1, fill='green')
```

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thank you!